# Ruby on Rails: How to print contents of variable in view and make checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a checklist in rails using form_for. This checklist is taken from a table which I gained in the create action of my sign_ins controller:

```
@content = OrientationContent.where(site_id: session[:site_id])
```

In my view I want to use the form_for helper to iterate through the list in @content:

```
<%= form_for(:sign_ups ) do |f| %>
 <% @content.each do |c| %>
    <%= f.check_box nil %> <%= c %> <br>

 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However this is not working and it produces two square brackets on the page: [].

How do I go through the list and print the name while creating a check box on the left of it? The check box does not have any meaning or data, I just need it present for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

In the controller, need to pluck an individual field:

```
@content = OrientationContent.where(site_id: 1).pluck(:content)
```

In the view, structure as so:

```
<%= form_for(:sign_ups) do |f| %>
 <% @content.each do |c| %>
    <%= f.check_box nil %> <%= c %> <br>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```